# VBA - Search for cell, grab contents to the right of cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working macro that loops through folder to open files and get important info from the columns of names "HOLDER" and "CUTTING TOOL" and printing all the info to one excel document, masterfile. It also prints the file name into column 1 and the name of the "Tooling Data Sheet" to column 4. I currently have that set up as printing cell J1.

This only works some of the time as the information is not always in J1. What I want to do is search for the header **"TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):"** as i have done with "HOLDER" and "CUTTING TOOL" but grab the contents in **one cell to the right of that header** and print it to the masterfile (as it currently works but instead of just printing J1, print cell to right of header). Any ideas?

*The information for the "TOOLING DATA SHEET" is printed in the second half of section (5). The major commented out sections in my code have been my attempts at solving this issue.*

**FULL CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim f As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, hc4 As Range, hc5 As Range, d As Range


    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")
    Set hc4 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("D1"), "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2


    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)
            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    'If InStr(ROW_HEADER, "HOLDER") <> "" Then
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                    'End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If

'''(4)
'                'find TDS on the source sheet
'                Set hc5 = HeaderCell2(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):")
'                If Not hc5 Is Nothing Then
'                    Set dict = GetValues(hc5.Offset(1, 0))
'                    'If InStr(ROW_HEADER, "HOLDER") <> "" Then
'                    If dict.count > 0 Then
'                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc4.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
'                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
'                    End If
'                    'End If
'                Else
'                    'header not found on source worksheet
'                End If


'(5)
            With WB
               'print TDS information
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                        'print the file name to Column 1
                        StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = objFile.Name

                        'print TDS name from J1 cell to Column 4
                        With ws
                            .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i, 4)
                            .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 4), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 4))
                        End With
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    '(7)
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim v
    Dim spl As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then

            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ";")
            v = spl(0)
            End If

            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ",")
            v = spl(0)
            End If

            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        'copy cell value if it contains some string "holder" or "cutting tool"
        If InStr(c.Value, sHeader) <> 0 Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

''(9)
''find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
'Function HeaderCell2(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
'    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
'    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToRight)).Cells
'        'copy cell value if it contains some string "holder" or "cutting tool"
'        If InStr(c.Value, sHeader) <> 0 Then
'            Set rv = c
'            Exit For
'        End If
'    Next c
'    Set HeaderCell2 = rv
'End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function


'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

**EDIT**
Current code attempt creating a function to call:

```
Function GetTDSName(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = Range("J1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1).Value
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetTDSName = ret
End Function
```

Comment: Without reviewing your full code my suggestion would be to use the `.find` method and grab the offset. IE `ValueYouNeed = Range(YourRange).Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1).Value` Regards,

Comment: Okay, I have written that as a function so I can access it in my main code.. do you know how I would reference it? Currently trying to write it as `StartSht.Cells(i,4) = GetTDSName(ws, 1)` in order to get the TDS Name from the worksheet and print it to column 4 of the StartSht @nbayly I have edited my question to include the function I am now working on

Comment: Depends how you are returning the results from your `GetTDSName` function. If you are returning the value as string you can just make `StartSht.Cells(i,4).Value2 = GetTDSName(ws, 1)`. If your returning as a range then `StartSht.Cells(i,4).Value2 = GetTDSName(ws, 1).Value2`. Untested but hopefully pushing you in the right direction.

Comment: When I do that, it highlights TDSName and gives back the error wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment @nbayly

Comment: Can you clarify what the error states and on what line? A couple of things I note: when you do `.find` it returns a Range object but you have not declares `ret` as a range object and you would need to do `Set ret = Range("...`; also in your `.find` your search range only has 1 cell and should have the complete searchable range. Change those couple of things and if you continue having errors post them here and we'll gladly assist you. Cheers,

Comment: thank you for your help @nbayly . I really appreciate it. I figured out the solution and posted it below

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

```
'print TDS name
            If Not Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set TDS = Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
                StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
            Else
                StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO TDS VALUE!"
            End If
            i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
    End With
```